# Is there a way to copy a complete page from one App to another in AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to copy a complete page from one AppMaker application to another AppMaker application?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this time there is no easy way to do it:

1. Export source app (top left corner menu button -> Export(.zip))
2. Export target app
3. Insert extracted page file into target app zip archive in pages
   folder
4. You may want to tag your last revision in target app before
   re-importing to be able to revert to that revision easily (just in
   case).
5. Import target app from modified zip (with additional page).
6. After importing you may also need to fix imported page: if it uses
   datasource that doesn't exist in this app, CSS for this page isn't
   imported, so you need to copy it manually from source app, etc.

Here is link to google groups discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/6IasuJWiA34